# Can I close an unnamed mysql connection?

Tags: php, mysql

I've been doing some upgrades to a friends website. But now it looks like the original programmer didn't close any mysql connections.. or at least I can't find any place where they closed them. The site fell over this morning and I thought it was due to the web server but turned out the database server was over loaded. I'm now looking at the code but being a bit rusty with php I'm not sure how to close the connections at the bottom of the page.

```
mysql_connect(localhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
@mysql_select_db($dbase);
```

This code is in a file that I don't want to touch unless I really have to.. Is there any way for me to close the connection without giving it a name?

```
mysql_close($connectionname);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Strange that that should happen, as PHP should close them automatically...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply close it without passing anything:

```
mysql_close();
```

If you only open one MySQL connection, that will be the one that gets closed.